# Maven сборка .jar сразу в несколько директорий

Tags: java, maven

Собственно из названия все понятно. В pom.xml можно указать директорию для сборки jar файла. Никак не пойму, как указать сразу несколько директорий, в которые будет помещен jar'ник. Например в Ant это делалось очень просто тегами `<jar destfile='/...'>`.

Comment: Можете добавить плагин ant-а и после шага package раскидать (скопировать) файлы куда необходимо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать использовать [`dependency:copy`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html) и привязать к фазе `install`. Так, после сборки файл будет раскопирован в разные директории.

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <!-- Первое расположение -->
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-first</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <!-- 
                            Плагин может копировать любые зависимости по координатам.
                            Поэтому приходится вставлять координаты текущего проекта
                            -->
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                                <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                                <version>${project.version}</version>
                                <type>${project.packaging}</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                        <outputDirectory>D:/</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <!-- Второе расположение -->
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-second</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                                <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                                <version>${project.version}</version>
                                <type>${project.packaging}</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                        <outputDirectory>D:/1/</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Не коротко и не просто, но сработает.

Comment: Сработало. Большего и не нужно, спасибо!

Comment: @Nanit Рад. Пожалуйста!